# Understanding of Credential Processes in an AD Domain

Tags: windows, authentication, active-directory, kerberos, rdp

I'm currently trying to understand how credentials are processed and registered in all (well the most...) cases possible during authentication.

Now from what I understand, LSA retreives all authentication requests, and depending on the protocol used, it then deals with credentials.

Then, only CredSSP (= RDP right ?) and NTML protocols make that the password gets registered in SAM, and that forever (because they go through NetLogon). Is that right ?

For Kerberos, because credentials aren't carried by NetLogon, they also aren't stored in SAM. But ! Like any other credentials, they're registered in LSASS, which only carries credentials for an user during the time he is logged in a session. I'm not sure about this part, and if it is right, when does it then gets rid of the credentials for the user ? Simply at the end of the session ?

(Is there also a way to check which users are in LSASS memory and SAM without using mimkatz or similar ?)

If someone could light me up on this, would be awesome :)

Have a great day !

Comment: To what end? It's not clear what you're asking specifically. Charting the path credentials take through Windows is an incredibly complicated thing and requires a dedicated chapter in a book to be thorough.

Comment: Actually to ask finer, during an RDP or NTML authentication to a machine, using a domain account, where are the credentials stored on this machine ? Lsass during the session yes but after the logout ? Only MS-CACHE ?

Comment: Credentials are never persisted to disk or across logon sessions. If you logout they're wiped from memory. There are cached credential validators that are hashes used to verify entered passwords that get stored in SAM, but they cannot be reversed to real creds.